# While importing data from My SQL to Neo4j Graph Database,some of the data in the tables are missing

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have created a SQL database with 6 tables.After this I have used the Neo4j ETL Tool to convert the data from MySQL to Neo4j.After the conversion I realized that some of the data in the tables are missing.For example I had created a 'Complaints' table with 20 entries.However only 10 entries have been mapped.

I was expecting all 20 complaints to be mapped as relationships between the 'Customer' node and the  'Product' node.But only 10 were mapped and the columns present in the Purchase table were missing in the relationship properties.How do I ensure that all the data gets imported?